# "error: cannot find symbol import com.liferay.portal.kernel.uuid.PortalUUID;" in Liferay 7.4

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, liferay, liferay-7

I am working with Liferay `portal-7.4-ga107` (with IntelliJ) and trying to do a training guestbook app following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com) from Liferay.
I have followed it perfectly and even repeated the process 3 times, but at the end of the `"Integrating the Back-end"` [step](https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360032887712-Integrating-the-Back-end) I always encounter this error right after deploying the module/portlet:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.uuid.PortalUUID;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class PortalUUID
  location: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.uuid
```

The error seems to be directly related to this dependency in the persistence classes (which are **auto-generated** in the process):

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.uuid.PortalUUID; //(highlighted as red in code)
```

Inside the persistence classes, `PortalUUID` is only "used" here:

```
    @Reference
    private PortalUUID _portalUUID;
```

and here:

```
    String uuid = _portalUUID.generate();
```

I've done a lot of research and tried a few things, with no luck. The error could be related to something that is outdated and I haven't found, or a change in `PortalUUID` for my version, I really don't know.

#### I'm using JDK 8 and gradle 6.9.2

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Relevant attempts:

I tried to deploy my portlet `guestbook-web` after finishing [this step](https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360032887712-Integrating-the-Back-end) from the Liferay tutorial, I expected it to get built successfully, but the `kernel.uuid.PortalUUID` dependency error appeared.

Afterwards, I tried replacing `PortalUUID` with `PortalUUIDUtil`, this last one didn't cause any errors in the code, but after deploying the module (`guestbook-web`), it didn't appear in the portal.

Finally, I saw in Liferay docs that `PortalUUIDUtil` has a `getPortalUUID()` method, I tried using `PortalUUIDUtil.getPortalUUID();` with no luck (the method doesn't even exist according to my IDE).

Comment: Please edit your question [to contain text instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Comment: I recall to have seen a similar question recently - and indeed [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78047061/13447). I just can't mark this as duplicate, as that other question has no accepted or upvoted answer. I've edited my answer from this question into that one. Maybe the additional content over there helps understanding more, if you need.

Comment: @OlafKock I already saw that question before while researching about the issue, but as it seemed abandoned, I chose to ask my own question with more information.

Comment: I've also updated my answer on that other question, as there are more issues than just the service-builder update. Due to that mismatch, I no longer count them as duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay 7.4 (after GA/U 100) [requires](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/23243892875917-PortalUUID-cannot-find-symbol-in-Service-Builder-module) the workspace version `9.0.4` or higher to generate ServiceBuilder code adapted to the [changed `PortalUUID` API](https://liferay.atlassian.net/browse/LPS-196204).

Make sure to configure your Liferay workspace *at least* like this in your settings.gradle:

```
dependencies {   
    classpath group: “com.liferay”, 
              name: “com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace”, 
              version: “9.0.4"
}
```

Comment: Could I know where did you get that information from? As far as I know, versions like Gradle 6.3 to 6.9 are the most compatible with Liferay 7.4

Comment: I'm confused: Gradle is _how a plugin is built_, but it has no effect on _what code is available to the plugin_ as a dependency. PortalUUID is no longer in the source code, and the implementation (I've linked it in my answer) does not register it any more. Due to being removed, it's no longer available to plugins. No matter how the plugin is compiled/built.

Comment: @OlafKock Why dont ask them? https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/23243892875917-PortalUUID-cannot-find-symbol-in-Service-Builder-module

Comment: @GonzaloRabasaSanMartín Please try that version of gradle workspace and confirm it works

Comment: @OlafKock I'm working with the last version available of the Liferay plugin (2.0.5). The persistence classes (along with the use of PortalUUID) are autogenerated when using the serviceBuilder provided by the plugin, it makes me think that the last version of Liferay plugin is outdated for Liferay 7.4. I'm checking if it works with gradle 9.0.4 as SilverSurfer requested.

Comment: @SilverSurfer as you may notice here: https://gradle.org/releases/ , it seems like gradle v9 doesn't exist. Maybe you were referring to the Liferay gradle plugin: https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-releases/com/liferay/com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace/. Im trying with this 9.0.4 Liferay gradle plugin.

Comment: As Gonzalo says: The article mentions the "Liferay Workspace" version. However, I call _that_ aspect of the linked article wrong, because I've just successfully tried using `PortalUUIDUtil.generate()` in a Liferay Workspace version 8.0.8. The available code is not dependent on the way a plugin is built. I'll try to get the article corrected or clarified. (Note: My usage was outside of Liferay ServiceBuilder - the requirement _might_ be for usage within ServiceBuilder)

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to clarify the version (for the workspace plugin, not gradle) and link the article in your answer - the link is really useful, thank you for finding it @SilverSurfer.

Comment: @OlafKock After using Gradle Liferay Plugin 9.0.4 as SilverSurfer requested, serviceBuilder is not using PortalUUID anymore, but using PortalUUIDUtil instead as you said. Although it appeared another error `Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.docs.guestbook.service; version="1.0.0"_ [Sanitized]` , but maybe it's better to leave it for another question/research.

Comment: @SilverSurfer I have now edited the comment stream into the answer and made the correction from gradle- to workspace-version. Please check if you agree with this edit and thank you again for finding the reference.

Comment: @GonzaloRabasaSanMartín consider accepting this answer, as it was the one that helped going to the root cause.

Comment: @OlafKock Im fine with your edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation (and API) seems to have changed recently, and the tutorial isn't updated yet.

Best bet is the [current PortalUUIDUtil class](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/uuid/PortalUUIDUtil.java), that uses `java.util.UUID` in its `generate` method.

I'd expect `PortalUUIDUtil.generate()` to be the new replacement. Use with a grain of salt: This is only from looking at the implementation, not at the tutorial/sample code.

And, as pointed out in a comment for another answer: It seems that the use within Liferay ServiceBuilder [requires newer ServiceBuilder implementations](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/23243892875917-PortalUUID-cannot-find-symbol-in-Service-Builder-module), so you'll need to run it within a newer Liferay Workspace, starting with version 9. The difference to the paragraphs above this is: ServiceBuilder is generating this code for you, and it has been adapted to the API change. With the proper Workspace version, you'll likely never see this issue, because the generated code already includes the necessary API change.